# ng-repeat inside ng-repeat-start

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

A beginner in angularJS, while tried ng-repeat inside ng-repeat-start intermittently the page breaks and shows angularjs code in the browser.

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in obj">{{key}}</tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="v in value">
      <div>{{v.address}}</div>
      <div>{{v.mobile}}</div>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
</table>
```

Trying to identify how this will work in browser. Does anyone knows for what reasons that this code will break?

The obj model structure:

```
{"name1":
  [{
    "address":"",
    "mobile":""
  },{
    "address":"",
    "mobile":""
  }],
"name2":
  [{
    "address":"",
    "mobile":""
  },{
    "address":"",
    "mobile":""
  }]
}
```

Forgot to mention the error that received intermittently:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:uterdir?p0=ng-repeat-start&p1=ng-repeat-end](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile%3auterdir?p0=ng-repeat-start&p1=ng-repeat-end)

[Solution Found so far]

Used nested ng-repeat instead of ng-repeat inside ng-repeat-start like

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
       <td>{{key}}</td>
       <td>
           <table>
               <tr ng-repeat="v in value">
                  <div>{{v.address}}</div>
                  <div>{{v.mobile}}</div>
               </tr>
           </table>    
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To help us, please post `obj` model.

Comment: In case that can help some of you guys, many people recommend not to use ng-repeat-start/end, even if it MIGHT be usefull in some very SPECIFIC moments, instead just put the HTML part you want to repeat inside a `<div><\div>` and apply a normal ng-repeat to this div.

Answer (score 0):

You mention "intermittently the page breaks" and the key here might be "intermittently" -- that would mean you've got FOUC (flash of unstyled content). One place to find answers is [Angular Tips and Tricks](http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED), an ongoing-updated collection of all kinds of neat things. For FOUC, Sofer recommends trying ng-bind or ng-cloack. I'm not sure which would work here (and there are other tricks, too) but you could start with checking the [documentation on ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak). That might at least point you in the right direction for how to keep the ng-repeat from kicking in (showing) until after everything's been compiled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but am using ng-cloak directive though. I updated my description with the error that received sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing the other day to dynamically create a table with X rows and Y columns.
Here's what I came up with:
JS:

```js
var MainCtrl = function() {
  this.rows = (function() {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 10;
    var rowArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      var cellArr = {
        cells: []
      };
      for (var j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        var cell = {};
        cell.x = j;
        cell.y = i;
        cellArr.cells.push(cell);
      }
      rowArr.push(cellArr);
    }
    return rowArr;
  })();
};
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tbody ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in main.rows">
      <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" x="{{cell.x}}" y="{{cell.y}}">        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```